# Python Numpy Standard deviation and mean

Tags: python

Can anyone please guide how to create Numpy array with predeifined Standard deviation and mean.
For example mean should be 75 and std should be 12

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50177594/create-an-array-with-a-pre-determined-mean-and-standard-deviation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html

in short, you can use

```
numpy.random.normal([mean], [standard deviation], [array size])
```

so for your example:

```
numpy.random.normal(75, 12, [array size])
```

Comment: Hello! How to Generate numbers with all positive numbers?

Comment: @Megan, you can't- not with normal distribution. look here for a more thorough explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683461/generating-a-gaussian-distribution-with-only-positive-numbers